# How to copy files that do not need to be compiled in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

Suppose that my project is like this:

```
├── dist
├── src
│   ├── greeter.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   └── test.txt
└── tsconfig.json
```

Only `greeter.ts` need to be complied to dir `dist`, but how about other files? How to copy other files to dir `dist`?

here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('ts',cb=>{
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['env']
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a another task to copy other files and add its dependency on other task

```
gulp.task('copyFile', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/**/*', //Include All files
        '!src/**/*.ts' //It will exclude typescript files           
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('ts', ['copyFile'], cb => {
    //Your existing code
});
```

Comment: Error: Invalid glob argument: ./src/**/*,false  @Satpal